# Images from PDF as Web service

Tags: linux, pdf

I want to convert PDF files into single page jpeg images on a linux machine. I have done this with ghostscript so far. This works fine but takes a lot of time for large Documents. Because I want to develop a web service it is problematic with long running scripts.
Are other possibilities?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: It was indeed a question for programming. I am looking for tools and hints for developement of a web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert from imagemagick instead. It's easier to use but I don't think it's faster. 
I think you really have to send the conversion process to background.
See this code on github
https://github.com/qstarx/pdfToImage

This is the code used on.
https://www.fototasse.com/pdfupload/